# Converting 8-bit RGB tif to single gray-scale image

Tags: qgis, raster, rgb

I have a tif image of soil thorium content (ppm) measured by gamma aerial spectroscopy. The original file is a 8 bit RGB image set in a rainbow-similiar pallet (blue>green>yellow>red>magenta). I have a jpg file about the legend, which was attached with the original file. The  thorium content ranges from 2 (blue) to 36 ppm (Fig. 1).

[image]

For modelling purposes, I want to convert this RGB file to a single raster of thorium content. I have already tested the a processing module of QGIS:

Raster > Conversion > RGB to PCT

The module transformed to a single band, but it produced a palleted band containing a unsorted color ramp (Fig. 2)

[image: Fig. 2]

Could I sort the color ramp and reclassify the raster values to match with the original values from the jpg legend? If it is possible, how could I sort the colors?

Is there another way to transform the RGB image to a gray-scale single band?

Comment: I have a same question. Have you found any answer?